# Зачем отправлять сообщения в GCM?

Tags: java, android

Я разбираюсь с примером от гугла о том как имплементировать GMS и тут есть такой кусок кода который я отправляет сообщения в GMS, но я не могу понять зачем отправлять сообщения в GMS? Этот блок кода привязан к кнопке и не понятно, что он тестирует при ее нажатии? Что и зачем отправляется на сервер?

```
public void onClick(final View view) {

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.send)) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

@Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
                    data.putString("my_action", "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
                    String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());

  ---->>>    gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                    msg = "Sent message";

                } catch (IOException ex) {   
                }
            }
```

Насколько я понимаю, это не регистрация устройства в GCM так как регистрация устройства происходит в этом блоке

```
private void registerInBackground() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                registrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + registrationId;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                // 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: Ваш сервер отправляет в GCM,  а он уже непосредственно доставляет клиенту (телефону/планшету).

Comment: Не совсем то что касается моего вопроса. Я подправил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

1) Для регистрации в GCM с клиента отправляем senderId и applicationId
2) При успешном процессе регистрации в GCM получаем ответ- registrationId
3) После отправляем полученный registrationId к себе на сервер и сохраняем в базу.
4) Ну и сервер будет слать пуши с сообщениями в GCM сервер, на указанные id-шники.

Вроде бы как-то так

Comment: Все верно вы описали, но это не совсем имеет отношение к моему вопросу... Можете посмотреть я подправил вопрос

Comment: Там в комментарие на английском написано что это сообщение само себе отправится. То есть просто для тестирования нотификации пример, я думаю

Comment: Можете подробнее объяснить, где это написано и как это связано с `gcm.send`? Какую нотификацию они тестируют? Я просто новичок и мне  совсем не понятен это ответ... Я вижу то, что отправка `register` и получение `registrationId` происходит автоматически и второе что я вижу это кнопка и привязанная к ней функция которая делает `gcm.send`... Зачем мне не понятно? и что в таком случае должно делать само `gcm`? Если это гугл указал в своем примере то зачем и как с этим работать?